# How to implement recurring events in calendar app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I wanted to implement this feature and I am not sure exactly how to do it. I basically have a Calendar app where I can create events. Upon creating events it shows it in the Calendar.

Now I have Calendars controller and Calender model and I have Events Controller and Event Model. I am using this association "Calendar has_many: events" and I have CRUD for events.

Till this point I can create single events, but now I am interested to create multiple events at the same time. By that what I mean is I want to create recurring events, how would I do that? Will I be able to do that with existing controllers and models or do I need more controllers and models?

This is my code for creating single events

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController

before_action :find_calendar, except: [:index]
def create

@event = @calendar.events.new event_params

if @event.save
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {redirect_to business_path(@business, calendar_id: @calendar.id)}
    format.js
  end
else
  render :new
end
end

private

def event_params
params.require(:event).permit([:summary, :unique_id, :time_of_day, :start_time, :end_time, {activity_ids:[]}, :calendar_id])
end



def find_calendar   

# @calendar = @business.calendar
@calendar = Calendar.find(params[:calendar_id])
end
```

Comment: Maybe you should show us some of your code you use to create a single event?

Comment: So you're asking for a good way to store and manage recurring events? E.g. a data structure that can efficiently handle start/end repeating events, maybe once-off specific removals etc?

Comment: @jozxyqk : I am asking how can I create recurring events? I can creating single events now. But how do I create recurring events, which seems to me is creating multiple events at the same time but with some different attributes

Answer (score 0):

I think you are wondering how to implement recurring event. In database level, it just create a single record. You should add extra attributes to record event_type(single event, recurring event...), event_start_time, event_end_time.

When rendering recurring event, based on the current page's time range, one recurring event will be converted into multiple single events.

You can take a look at the js version calendar implementation http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/, which will give you some hints.